# How can I create a morph animation with sliders on three.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, slider, blender

I created a morph animation (default: a slim avatar and shape key: a fat avatar) on blender and now I am trying to export it to three.js and display it using a slider. So, when the slider is dragged to right or left, the avatar changes its shape, getting fatter or slimmer. But I do not know how to program in javascript this functionality. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) as a slider and morphTarget to effect the vertices position for this.

You can read the source code from this example.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets

But Basically, you push morphTarget to [geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) and use `mesh.morphTargetInfluences` to effect the influence of the morph target vertices.

Comment: What are morphTargetInfluences and how do they work?

Comment: Morph targets are sets of geometry vertices positions for automatic interpolation between them. You can change geometry appearance in real time, using different vertices positions written in morphTargetInfluences[0], morphTargetInfluences[1], morphTargetInfluences[nSet].  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952916/morph-targets-three-js

Comment: accept and upvote the answer if you think it answers your question.